# How can I add the numbers for IEEE in my own \DeclareCiteCommand?

Tags: biblatex

I added a second bibliography in order to have a ludography for video games listed separately. I use the following configuration of the `biblatex` package:

```
\usepackage[%
  backend=biber,
  url=true,
  style=ieee,
  maxnames=4,
  minnames=3,
  maxbibnames=99,
  giveninits,
  uniquename=init,
  dashed=false]{biblatex}
```

I followed the tutorial from the following website: https://www.davideaversa.it/blog/manage-videogames-bibliography-latex/

So I added my two bibliographies like this:

```
\bibliography{bibliography}
\addbibresource{ludography.bib}
```

And print them like this:

```
\printbibliography[title={Bibliography},nottype=software]{}
\printbibliography[title={Ludography},type=software]
```

I added the following new cite command in order to cite video games in-text:

```
\DeclareCiteCommand{\citegame}
{\boolfalse{citetracker}%
    \boolfalse{pagetracker}%
    \usebibmacro{prenote}}
{\ifentrytype{software}{%
        \printfield{title}%
        \setunit{\addspace}%
        \printtext[parens]{%
            \printnames{author}%
            \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
            \printfield{year}}}{\GenericError{}{Not a game entry}{}{}}}
{\multicitedelim}
{\usebibmacro{postnote}}
```

It works fine, but the way it shows up in-text does not include the typical IEEE reference number, e.g. [4]. The `.bib`-entry

```
@software{bioshockinfinite,
  author = {{Irrational Games}},
  title = {BioShock: Infinite},
  url = {http://www.bioshockinfinite.com/main.php},
  version = {1.1.25},
  date = {2013-03-26},
}
```

will show up as *Bioshock: Infinite* (Irrational Games, 2013) in the text and as e.g.

> [4] Irrational Games. *Bioshock: Infinite*. Version 1.1.25. Mar. 26, 2013.

in the ludography.

**First question**: How can I edit `\DeclareCiteCommand` in order to make the number show up in-text? It should show *Bioshock: Infinite* (Irrational Games, 2013) [4]. The number should also work as a hyperlink to the entry in the ludography, just as the normal `\cite` command does it.

**Second question**: How can I add the publisher to the entry in the ludography? When I add it in the `.bib`-file as "`publisher = {{abc}}`" as I do in my normal bibliography it won't show up.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: `\bibliography{bibliography}\addbibresource{ludography.bib}` is an odd mix of old and new, do yourself a favour and use `\addbibresource{bibliography.bib}\addbibresource{ludography.bib}` (of course this has no effect on any of the things your are asking).

Comment: About your second question: `@software` does not have a `publisher`, but it has the functionally equivalent `organization`.

Comment: @moewe Thank you! It shows up now, however the format is not quite right. I guess I would have to change the type then, as type software does not seem to fit the desired format.

Comment: The formatting of `organization` in `@software`/`@misc` is exactly the same as `publisher` in `@book` in the standard styles. So if you expect `publisher` to do the right thing, `organization` should work for you. I think `@software` is a good type for computer/video games, so I would not look into changing the type you use: I would look into changing the output `@software` gives you. If you need help with that, just ask a new question explaining in detail what you need and what you have at the moment. (Please do that in a compilable example document and not just with code snippets.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an attempt to slightly redefine `\gamecite` in such a way that it produces both the `<title> (<author>, <year>)` and the numeric citation.

First we separate out the `<title> (<author>, <year>)` printing in `\gamecite` into a bibmacro to make things easier to follow. Then `\citegame` just needs to call the new bibmacro if appropriate and can print the numeric citation label with `cite:print:subentry:full`.

Ideally one would try and integrate this into the normal `\autocite` and `\cite` commands such that no new command is necessary, but with `style=ieee,`, which is based on `style=numeric-comp,`, this is *extremely* difficult.

Note that this solution requires an up-to-date version of `biblatex`. It was tested with v3.16 (2020-12-31), but it should also work with v3.15 (2020-08-16).

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[%
  backend=biber,
  style=ieee,
  minnames=3,
  maxcitenames=4,
  maxbibnames=99,
  giveninits,
  uniquename=init,
  dashed=false,
  url=true,
]{biblatex}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}

\newbibmacro{gamecite}{%
  \printfield[citetitle]{labeltitle}%
  \setunit{\addspace}%
  \printtext[parens]{%
    \printnames{labelname}%
    \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
    % hack to display the date only as year
    \csdef{blx@dateformat@date}{year}%
    \mkdaterangeyear{}%
  }%
}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\citegame}
  {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\ifentrytype{software}
     {\usebibmacro{gamecite}%
      \setunit{\addspace}}
     {\GenericError{}{Not a game entry}{}{}}%
   \printtext[brackets]{%
     \ifbool{bbx:subentry}
       {\usebibmacro{cite:print:subentry:full}}
       {\usebibmacro{cite:print:labelnumber}}}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}

\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{\jobname.bib}
@software{bioshockinfinite,
  author  = {{Irrational Games}},
  title   = {BioShock: Infinite},
  url     = {http://www.bioshockinfinite.com/main.php},
  version = {1.1.25},
  date    = {2013-03-26},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
Lorem \autocite{sigfridsson}
ipsum \citegame{bioshockinfinite}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Lorem [1] ipsum BioShock: Infinite (Irrational Games, 2013) [2]]